# Laravel Request facade NOT getting FormData

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5, vuejs2

I trying to save a picture from vuejs frontend to laravel backend. I used jQuery Ajax to sent the form data.

```
var mydata = new FormData();
mydata.append('mypic', blob);

$.ajax(myurl, {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                  'Authorization':'Bearer ' + mytoken,
                  'Content-Type':'application/json'
              },
              data: mydata,
              processData: false,
              contentType: false,
              success: function () {
                console.log('Upload success');
              },
              error: function () {
                console.log('Upload error');
              }
            });
```

In Laravel, I tried

```
return $request->all();
```

but it returns an empty array.

I also tried to log the `$request` with laravel Log

```
Log::info($request);
```

But it logs an empty array in the `laravel.log` file

```
[2017-09-04 03:55:50] local.INFO: array (
)
```

I thought the `formData.append()` was not working, so I log the formData

```
// Display the key/value pairs
        for (var pair of mydata.entries()) {
            console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
        }
```

This worked well. It logs the entry I appended to formdata. I don't understand why laravel Request facade is not getting it.